# Expand and Collapse in gridview by clicking on Hyperlink(Not plus and Minus Symbols)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anybody help me on writing code for Expanding and Collapse in Gridview by clicking on Hyperlink.
we have a grid with multiple columns. and we have one coloumn in the middle of Grid and that entire column is a Hyperlink. means numbers with hyperlink. I want to write code for Expand and Collapse for that column. In middle we cannot keep any symbols like Minus and Plus.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdrequisitions" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="grdrequisitions_PageIndexChanging"
    OnRowCommand="grdrequisitions_RowCommand"
    CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped table-page new-table" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" PageSize="15" EmptyDataText="No records found" class="WordWrap">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="ChkSelectChanged" onclick="CheckBoxCheck(this);" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkforcePlanStatus" HeaderText="Status" />  <%--1--%>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="WorkforcePlanID" HeaderText="WFP ID" HtmlEncode="false" />  <%--2--%>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CRMOpportunityCode" HeaderText="O2R ID" />   <%--3--%>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="DeliveryUnit" HeaderText="Delivery Unit" /> <%--4--%>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerAccount" HeaderText="Account" /> <%--5--%>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# Openings"> <%--6--%>

    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTotalHeadCount" Style="color: #0000b3;"
           runat="server"
           CausesValidation="false"
           CommandName="TotalHeadCount"
           Text='<%# Eval("TotalHeadCount") %>'
           CommandArgument='<%# Eval("WorkforcePlanID") %>'
           EnableTheming="False">                                                   
     </asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

here is the code. I have to write code for Expand and Collapse for  `ID="lnkTotalHeadCount"`. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes. Hopefully, It will answer your question.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleColumn(link)
    {
        var div = $(link).siblings('.countDiv');
        //alert(div.length);
        $(div).toggle();
    }
</script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="# Openings"> 
<ItemTemplate>
    <a style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="toggleColumn(this)"><%# Eval("Count") %></a>      
    <div class="countDiv">
        Total Count: 20
    </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Default.aspx.cs file:

```
  namespace aspnetWeb
      {
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Student> list = new List<Student>();

            for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
            list.Add(new Student { ID = 1, Count = 20 });

            GridView1.DataSource = list.AsQueryable();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    public class Student
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
 }
```